# C++ TCP server still reading data after client disconnects

Tags: c++, c, sockets, select

I made a server that uses `select()` to check witch of the socket descriptors have data in them, but apparently select marks a socket to be ready to read from even after the client disconnects, and I get garbage values.

I have found this post on stack overflow:

> select (with the read mask set) will return with the handle signalled, but when you use ioctl* to check the number of bytes pending to be read, it will be zero.  `

My question is what is ioctl* and how to use it? And an example would be very good.

Comment: "*... be ready to read from even after the client disconnects, and I get garbage values.*" what was the return value returned by this `read()` call? Was it 0? If yes: That simply ment the client closed the conection.

Comment: On what platform are you using select? On windows you have Completion Ports, on Linux you have epoll, on Mac kQueue, on Solaris completion ports, etc. select is old. You have also boost::asio...

Comment: @neagoegab: on linux, and I'd like to keep using it.

Comment: @alk: that seems to work fine. please post the comment as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a call to `read()` on a socket (file) descriptor returns `0`, that simply means the other side of the connection had shutdown and closed the connection.

Note: A `select()` waiting for possible "events" on set(s) of socket (file) descriptors will also return when a connection represented by one of the `fd_set`'s passed to `select()` had been shutdown.

Comment: I.e., the take-home is: stop selecting the socket for reading when `read()` first returns 0. You can keep using the socket to write, of course; you won't know whether the other end is still reading until you try a write and see whether there's an error! [Obviously, you're already checking return value of `read()` in some way, or you wouldn't know how much of buffer you passed in was filled...]

Comment: @NicholasWilson actually I didn't check the return value of read() becuause i designed a protocol where the client would first send 4 bytes that the server would read as an int which tells the server how many bytes the client has sent, and then I would read that number of bytes from the client.

Comment: @IonutHulub I thought that might be the case! You simply *must* check the return value of `read` and `write`. RTFM: "It is not an error if the number of bytes read is smaller than the number of bytes requested; this may happen for example because  fewer bytes are actually available right now, or because `read()` was interrupted by a signal." You absolutely may not assume read completely filled in the buffer passed. Even without the EINTR issue, you might get unlucky with the network, splitting the data into two packets, and you call `read` before the second one comes in. Ditto for write.

Answer (score 3):

Check the usual errors people make when using [`select(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/select.2.html):

- Always re-initialize `fd_set`s you give to [`select(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/select.2.html) on every iteration - these are input-output arguments that system call modifies for you.
- Re-calculate `fd_max`, the first argument, on every iteration.
- Check for errors from all system calls, check the value of [`errno(3)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/errno.3.html).

And, yes, [`read(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/read.2.html) returns zero when the other side closed TCP connection cleanly, don't use that socket anymore, just [`close(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/close.2.html) it.